# Gatsby XSS Prevention

Tags: reactjs, security, xss, gatsby

I've read that React only prevents XSS in children and not props. Is this code an XSS vulnerability?

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"import Layout from "../components/layout"

export default ({ data }) => (  <Layout>
    <h1>About {data.site.siteMetadata.title}</h1>
    <p>{data.body}</p>
    <img src={data.url} />
  </Layout>
)
```

Should I be using children and call the component like this?

```
(data) => <Component>
  <h1>About {data.site.siteMetadata.title}</h1>
  <p>{data.body}</p>
  <img src={data.url} />
</Component>
```

as opposed to:

`(data) => <Component {data} />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That snippet isn't XSS vulnerable, you could check it out by yourself.

```
// import React and others ...

function MyComponent({ inject, children }) {
  return (
    <main>
      <div>{inject}</div>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </main>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <MyComponent inject="<script>console.log('Executed from prop')</script>">
      {'<script>console.log("Executed from children")</script>'}
    </MyComponent>
  );
}
```

Script tags are rendered as string nodes. The only way you have to bypass that is by using prop `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, that way you get XSS vulnerable, hence the name.

I hope it helps!